# How to construct a generalized linear model with link function $h(x) = \text{sigm}\left(r\sin(x\beta)\right)$

Tags: generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, modeling, nonlinear-regression

I'm new in generalized linear models (GLM) and I'm interested to know on how would one go about and construct a GLM and fit it with maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) when then link function $h(x)$ would be:

$$\mu_y =h(x) = \text{sigm}\left(r\sin(x\beta)\right)\;\;\beta>0, \;x,r\in\mathbb{R},$$

where $\text{sigm}$ is the logistic function: $\displaystyle\text{sigm}(rz) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-rz}}$. The parameter $r$ is a constant user defined value, $y$ is the response value, $\mu_y$ is the expected value of $y$, $x$ is an independent (explanatory) variable and $\beta$ is a parameter which I want to optimize given some data set $(x_1,y_1), ...(x_n,y_n)$.

**My question is:** with these details in mind, how should I now proceed in order to construct my GLM model with MLE?

P.S. the distribution of $y$ can be anything you want, I'm just trying to learn this via example. Take the distribution of $y$ be some simple exponential distribution.

Comment: You need to first define what the random component of your model is.  That is, what distribution are you assuming $y$ follows?  I think your notation may be a little confused - $r\sin(x\beta)$ is not going to be between 0 and 1.

Comment: Thank you for your help, for me the distribution is no matter. Choose any distribution you want. I'm just trying to learn this stuff. But I am little bit confused about your $r\sin(x\beta)$ comment :) could you explain more? Why should it be between 0 and 1?

Comment: Ah, got it now. I will fix the notation, thnx.

Comment: I'm not an expert on GLMs... but aren't link functions determined by the distribution of the $y_i$, and not the other way around?

Comment: No, link functions are a choice, but you ARE limited by what your random component is.  For example in logistic regression, $p$ must be between 0 and 1 and thus logit and probit are usually used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your edit, your question makes more sense now.  First thing to notice is that the sigmoid function is actually the inverse of the logit function.  And thus you can rewrite this as

$$\text{logit}(h(x)) = r\sin(x\beta)$$

Which looks ***almost*** like a logistic regression GLM.  However, this is a nonlinear model, since the $\beta$ is inside the trig function.  Solving this would involve a home-made MLE method.

An interesting route to go would be to expand this by its Taylor expansion and simply perform a logistic regression.